# RMarkdown: how to print formula inline

Tags: r, r-markdown

Given a linear model:

```
fit <- lm(mpg~., mtcars)
```

I tried `r formula(fit)` to print the model/formula inline, but trying to knit the RMarkdown file to PDF or HTML gives errors (error in vapply...)

If it do the same thing inside a triple quoted code chunk, it works fine:

````
```{r}
formula(fit)
```
````

`formula(fit)` prints the formula on the R interpreter as I would like.

Is there a limitation to what can be done in an inline code chunk, or am I  missing something?

Comment: I couldn't replicate your error, both when knitting to pdf and to html.

Comment: @Heroka Apologies, I corrected my example code from "lm(mpg~wt, mtcars)" to "lm(mpg~., mtcars)". I am knitting to PDF, but I tried HTML as well with the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why exactly, but I think the issue lies in the structure and formatting of a formula-object. I'm guessing that the objects get converted to character in order to be printed. This is why it works (albeit in a weird sequence) for one independent variable, but doesn't work for multiple independent variables.

A workaround is to use

```
`r format(formula(fit))`
```

As inline code, it gave me the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as I wanted. One side question: how did you escape the single backquotes (`) so that they show up in your code snippet on stackoverflow?

Comment: No special escape, just four spaces in front m